# Does the order of bitwise shift and AND operations matter

Tags: bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

The two statements below give the same results:

```
(number & 0x02) >> 1 == 1

((number >> 1) & 1) == 1
```

Is there any advantage to use one before the other?

Comment: No. They are the same. But save and operation by comparing to 0x02 instead of 1. Do (number & 0x02) == 0x02